# A JFET based light sensor

Tags: jfet

[image]

I am working on a LDR based JFET project which would turn on automatically when it is sufficiently dark.

Accordingly, I have designed this circuit.  Is this practical? Also when the LDR value reaches 0 ohms the gate-source junction will be fully negative, but since the junction is reverse biased will it consume any power from the left side battery? I am not interested about the resistor values here, I just want to know whether the topology is correct.

Comment: People indicate batteries backward often enough that I just don't bother remembering what the polarity should be -- it may be good to edit your schematic to indicate battery +.

Comment: when drawing circuit diagrams, please follow convention ... V+ on top, Gnd on bottom, if present, V- below Gnd ... inputs on left, outputs on right ... it is ok to have inputs on right and outputs on left if your native language uses right to left writing

Comment: @TimWecott long is "+",  short "-"

Comment: Do you really want to use 2 batteries?

Comment: Haven't you notice that you have used a P-Channel JFET instead of an N-channel one? Thus the gate current will flow because now the source -gate diode is forward biased.

Comment: It's not so easy to use the usual JFET, p or n type either, as a good on/off switch.

Comment: @jonk why? can you briefly say?

Comment: @Sayan Because it's a terrible switch. There's no real ON to it. You can turn it OFF. But there's always going to be about a >= 1 V magnitude drop across the device, when ON (gate and source are at the same potential.) That's not a great switch. It is fine for some uses as a switch. (But complicated, still then.) Don't get me wrong. It's just not a great switch for turning on an LED.

Comment: Issues with this circuit: 1) the LED is always in reverse mode so cannot light up 2) The LDR is in series with the JFET's gate, you did bias the gate correctly with a negative voltage (\$V_{GS} < 0\$) meaning there is **no gate current flowing**. That means that the LDR receiving light (low resistance) or not (high resistance) **isn't going to make any difference at all**. No current flowing means no voltage is dropped. So if you turned around the LED it would light up, if there's light on the LDR or not. If you want a proper light sensor, use a different circuit.

Comment: @jonk thank you, I understood the issue now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The battery polarity is drawn differently than it's said in the question text (noticed already by commentators). If we assume the text is what's wanted it will not work. LDR resistance variations do not affect Vgs because there's no gate current ==>> light variations have no effect to the fet conductivity, the current of the led stays the same in dark and in light.

You need a voltage divider to generate voltage variations with LDR. If you use a bipolar transistor instead of fet you can control the base current with light on LDR.

You can set easily predictable voltage treshold and hysteresis if you use a comparator IC to sense what voltage a voltage divider with LDR outputs. Hysteresis is needed to avoid ON-OFF oscillations near the treshold.